# access getInitialProps fetched data inside getServerSideProps function

Tags: next.js

I'm using Nextjs in my project and on the first render I'm sending api request inside getInitialProps in _app to get some global data and access them through all my app in the clientside.
My problem is some of this data is an object that i need to be used inside getServersideProps in a dynamic page to redirect the user if the route wasnt included inside the object that i got from getInitialprops in _app so how can i get that object from getInitialprops in _app in getServersideProps of /[dynamic]

Note :I can access this object in clientside through props but i need a way to access it in serverside inisde getServersideProps

Comment: You can't - `getInitialProps` in `_app` and `getServerSideProps` in your pages do not have access to each other's context/data. I suggest you fetch the data in `getServerSideProps` instead.

Comment: well I know that but I need a way to have kind of global data to be accessed inside `getServerSideProps` and i was thinking about cache using `memory-cach` or any node js module that can help me in this or storing the request object inisde file system but i dont know if that is conventional or not